# I am making a website using bootstrap, I have made the card responsive but i can't make the image in the card responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This is My Format right now  on phone/dekstop

```
++img++ ++Title++ 
        ++SNIPPET++
```

I want to create it in such a way that it looks like this on phone

```
++img++
++Title++
++Snippet++
```

This is how i want to design in the card but i don't know how

This is The HTML code I am making this project on  django so ignore this part {}

```
 {% for post in object_list %}
     {% if post.header_image %}
   

      <div class="container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 " onclick="location.href='{%url 'article-details' post.pk %}';" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 mt-3">
    
                <div class="card ">
                    <div class="card-horizontal">
                        <div class="img-square-wrapper col-sm-4">
                       <img class="responsive" src="{{post.header_image.url}}" alt="Card image cap">
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                           <a href="{%url 'article-details' post.pk %}"> <h4 class="card-title"> {{post.title}}</h4></a>
                            <p class="card-text">{{post.snippets}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <small class="text-muted">{{post.post_date}}</small>
                            </div>
                                </div>
    
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                 {%endif%}
                              {% endfor %}
```

THIS the CSS part I have been trying all sorts of thing but its not happening, I dont know know what to do.

```
.item{
    margin: auto;
    padding:auto;
}
.flex-container-center  {
    justify-content: center;

}


.text{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;


}
.text2{
    color: black;

}

.list-col *{
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    outline: 5px black;

}


.card-horizontal {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;


}
.card-horizontal:hover{
    border: 1px solid #777;

}
img {
 border: 1% solid #ccc;
 display: block;
  margin-left: 10%;
    width: 100%;
  height: auto;

}
img:hover{
border: 1% solid #777;

}

.responsive{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: bottom;

}
```

Rendered in desktop:
[image]

Rendered on Mobile:
[image]

Can anyone help me to understand what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Here It is, I removed unnecessary classes from styles.
Used [col-md-4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#row-columns) and [w-100](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent)

```css
.item{
    margin: auto;
    padding:auto;
}
.flex-container-center  {
    justify-content: center;

}

.text{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    color: black;
}
.text2{
    color: black;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.list-col *{
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    outline: 5px black;

}

.card:hover{
    border: 1px solid #777;

}

img:hover{
border: 1% solid #777;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 col-xl-10 " onclick="location.href='#';" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mt-3">
            <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-horizontal row">
                    <div class="img-square-wrapper col-md-4">
                        <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150C/O" alt="Card image cap">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a href="#">
                            <h4 class="card-title"> Title</h4>
                        </a>
                        <p class="card-text">Lorem Epsum</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">11-02-2021</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a Bootstrap class for making images responsive: `img-fluid`.

Put this class in your img tag, and it should work without having to use other classes to make it look as you want.

Refer to: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/images/#responsive-images.
This link is for Bootstrap 5, but it works the same in Bootstrap 4.